# Interpretation of the excitations of the Klein-Gordon Field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, klein-gordon-equation, identical-particles

[image: photo taken from the Lecture notes of Prof David Tong]

Having quantized the Klein- Gordon field and having described the respective hamiltonian in terms of creation and annihilation operators, one finds that eqn 2.49 (in the photo) is satisfied(because of the commutation relations of the creation operators), thus interprets the excitations as bosons. From eqn 2.49 one can also show that the state $|p,q\rangle$ is symmetric under permutation , since if T is a permutation operator then T $|p,q\rangle$ =$|q,p\rangle$ which from Eqn 2.49 is equal to $|p,q\rangle$ , thus the state $|p,q\rangle$ as per the symmetrization postulate is a physical state representing bosons since it is symmetric under permutation. Doesn't that violate indistinguishability, because such a state has particle one with momentum P and particle 2 with momentum q ?The photo is from the lecture notes of Professor David Tong

Comment: No. $|p,q\rangle$ means that there is one boson with momentum $p$ and one with $q$, but you don't number the particles (as is not possible) and say particle 1 has momentum $p$ and particle 2 has momentum $q$ (or vice versa).

Comment: Then how is  $|q, p\ rangle different ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Different from what?

Comment: Tobias Fünke For some reason Tex commands ain't working in the comments , how is the state (p, q) different from (q, p) Physically?Because then both states represent 2 particles , one with momentum p and the other with momentum q.

Comment: Indeed, there is no difference: It is the same state! That's the point of the symmetrization, i.e. the commutation relations of the creation operators. See also equation $(2.49)$ in the cited text...